# Convenience method for getting the values out of an array of promises in Bluebird

Tags: promise, bluebird

I have the following code

```
value1: string;
value2: string;
...
activate(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.all([
        this.promise1().then(value1 => this.value1 = value1),
        this.promise2().then(value2 => this.value2 = value2)
    ]);
}
```

Is there a convenience method for something like this?

I tried the following but did not work as I had hoped

```
return Promise.all([
    this.value1 = this.promise1().value(),
    this.value2 = this.promise2().value()
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single `then` callback and *destructuring assignment* syntax, and initialize `value1`, `value2` there:

```
activate(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise
      .all([
        this.promise1(),
        this.promise2()
      ])
      .then([value1, value2] => {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may already be such a convenience method in bluebird, not sure, but I wrote my own that seems to do what you want

```
const objectPromise = obj => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return Promise.all(Object.values(obj)).then(results => Object.assign({}, ...results.map((result, index) => ({[keys[index]]: result}))));
};
```

To use it

```
value1: string;
value2: string;
...
activate(): Promise<any> {
    return objectPromise({value1: this.promise1, value2: this.promise2()})
    .then(results => Object.assign(this, results));
}
```

---

> On *searching* Bluebird **documentation**, I came across [Promsie.props](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html)

So

```
value1: string;
value2: string;
...
activate(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.props({value1: this.promise1, value2: this.promise2()})
    .then(results => Object.assign(this, results));
}
```

should do what you want